# Chat application, client-request server-respond model unsuitable?

Tags: c#, wcf, chat

From what I understand, in a client-server situation, the process used is 'client makes request, server responds'. But that doesnt sound like it would work for a chat application. Both users need to be able to send each other messages whenever they like. So how is this generally handled with sockets?

And to follow on from that, I would like to use WCF, how would you handle this in WCF?

Comment: Do you mean timing-wise (receiver not knowing when there is a new message)? Or do you mean you want to excise the server completely (p2p) ?

Comment: Yes I want to do it without a 3rd party server...ie p2p. Are socket applications able to handle this or do they require a 3rd party server for clients to post message to?

Answer (score 0):

Duplex communication in WCF can help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645026(v=vs.95).aspx